# Access to the application pool is denied

Tags: c#, iis

i try this code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525598.aspx
but when i run. show error "Access is denied"
Can someone help me

Comment: It means you dont have access rights

Answer (score 0):

You probably need elevated privileges to recycle the app pool,which means the app pool this site runs under needs to run with the correct account.